# How to make "single post" permalink maintain it's sub-page structure

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, pages, url-rewriting, single

I have a custom post type called "Classes", and I have multiple sub-pages for my site for each different schools classes page (which loops through said custom post type)

I.E

http://www.Schooldistrict.com/School1/classes

http://www.Schooldistrict.com/School2/classes

http://www.Schooldistrict.com/School3/classes

Each school has different classes, and when you access

http://www.Schooldistrict.com/School1/classes

It will only show the classes that pertain to that specific school, I've done this and it works fine. The issue comes up when you actually click on a specific class and go to the classes single page.

What should be:

http://www.Schooldistrict.com/School1/classes/computer-science

Instead comes out to:

http://www.Schooldistrict.com/classes/computer-science

Losing the specific school's URL and sub-page in the permalink hierarchy.
What can I do to maintain this structure in the URL hierarchy?

Comment: You could set it up as a MultiSite, with each school as its own separate sub-site. That would set the homepage of each sub-site to http://www.schooldistrict.com/school#/ and in that way each one's archive at http://www.schooldistrict.com/school#/classes/ would preserve the /school#/ in the URL.

Comment: How do you store which school each class belongs to?

Comment: @peter-k WP handles Category, subcategory, page and subpage for URL's directly, just assign the pages according your hierarchy you don't need a multisite.

Comment: @Milo I have each school as a custom taxonomy that I check off on each posts edit page, so if you check off School1 and School2 for "Mathematics" class, then "Mathematics" will appear on both School1 and School2's archive loops.

Comment: @Fernando I don't quite understand what you mean, assign what pages to what exactly?

Comment: @peterk You are handling sub pages, so you need pages as parent and other as child, so URL appears like domanin.com/page-parent1/page-child1 and so on. also can be included a category is defined inside your CTP's. Inside your loops you need to query one taxonomy. Please read this topic https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies then https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks and then how to code a query.

Comment: @FernandoBaltazar I do have them as sub pages and parents, the issue comes up when you actually click on an individual post, where it takes away the sub page heirarchy and just comes out at domain.com/posts/post instead of domain.com/sub-page/posts/post